# Updating a DataGridView from a List

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, which needs to be updated from a List, when a button is pressed. The list is populated with the results from a database extraction.

However, when I execute,

```
 DataGridView.Update(list);
```

Nothing happens.
An also, I found these "solutions":

1. Use a `BindingList`:

```
BindingList&lt;Meal> mVals=new BindingList&lt;Meal>();
```

2. Reset the `DataSource` to `null`, then re-update:

```
orderGridView.DataSource = null;
orderGridView.DataSource = mVals;
```

However, none of these work for me. My `DataGridView` does not get updated as I expect it to.

This is the code is used:

```
String mName=Convert.ToString(itemPanel.SelectedItem);
Meal ml = new Meal();
BindingList<Meal> mVals=new BindingList<Meal>();

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=CHAYU\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=restaurantApp; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30"))
{
    string oString = "Select * from Meal where mealName='mName'";
    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            ml.mealID = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["mealId"]);
            ml.mealName = oReader["mealName"].ToString();
            ml.price = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["price"]);
            ml.timeToProduce = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["timeToProduce"]);
            ml.availability = true;
            ml.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quant.Text);
            mVals.Add(ml);
        }
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
orderGridView.DataSource = null;
orderGridView.DataSource = mVals;
```

Answer (score 0):

`mVals` appears to be empty, you should replace the `mList.Add(ml)` to `mVals.Add(ml)`

**Edit**

Also check below:

- `string oString = "Select * from Meal where mealName='mName'";`
  mName is not a variable.
- orderGridView.AutoGenerateColumns is true?
- Meal property is public?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in copying. The code doesn't work like that either